# selenium throwing element not visible exception error when element is actually visible in the page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, paypal, webdriver

I am trying to login in the sandbox Paypal application using the given url but,It throws element not visible exception error when trying to find the email id and password field in the page using the below code.

**Code to reproduce an issue**

```
driver.get("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-7NA824468C3295748#/checkout/login");
Thread.sleep(20000);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='email']")).sendKeys("shariftest@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='password']")).sendKeys("test@1234");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

Its very strange that these element locators are absolutely correct and its visible in the page, but still throw an error when trying to find the element using selenium.

Please try the above code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the source html, both input fields have `display: none` as style. That's why you can't sendKeys to them.

```
<input id="email" name="login_email" type="email" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email" style="display:none">
```

You can use JavaScript to set the value, example for the email field:

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'you@yourprovider.nl'", driver.findElement(By.id("email")));
```

Comment: I tried the code you provided, but didnt work. It does not send the key. Have you executed the above code

Comment: did you checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Javascript implementation:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('email').setAttribute('value', 'shariftest@gmail.com')");
```

Comment: @Sharif I've updated my answer. Implement it and let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: I tried but its not working .It is not throwing any exception but it does not send the key.